# Visualize comparison of two variables with small deviation in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization

What is the best way to visualize following variables: distributed around some high value with small deviation?

Problem details:

- All the deviation is concentrated at the top of the chart, which is not user friendly
- Don't want to lose absolute values
- Want to see comparison of variables

Attaching my visualization attempts which I don't like

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The series appear to be only weakly related. Experiment suggests that showing both on logarithmic scale doesn't help. I'd use two panels as in your first display, but see absolutely no need to show zero on the $y$ axis; obeying that dogma just produces curves too flat to be instructive.

Comment: For what purpose is the visualization? What kind of features in the data do you want to be able to see from the visualization? variation with time? correlation? else? Answer will depend on such information!

Comment: Main purpose is monitoring this two variables on daily base. Say, these are some revenue KPI-s. Recognize possible correlations ass well.

Answer (score 1):

All continuous Axes in Tableau have the option to always 'Include zero' or not.

In all your examples you can right-click the y-Axis, choose 'Edit Axis...', and then deactivate 'Include zero' in the top right corner of the 'General'-Tab.